# C# can't insert into Data Source

Tags: c#, datasource

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Clienti (parola,nume,prenume,adresa,email,kcal_zilnice) VALUES (@Parola,@Nume,@Prenume,@Adresa,@Email,2000)", conn);
    cmd2.Prepare();
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parola", passBox.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Nume", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = nameBox.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Prenume", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pnameBox.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Adresa", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = adressBox.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = emailBox.Text;
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed! " + exception.Message);
}
MessageBox.Show("User Created!");
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I even tried to replace @Parola with 'abc' but it does not work. I don't get any error message. Every time I get "User Created", but when I look into the DB I get all the fields NULL(no records where created).

Comment: what exception?

Comment: what happens if you change it from SqlException to just exception ... maybe something else is complaining.

Comment: Reading the MSDN docs (I've not seen Prepare() before), I think .Prepare() should be called after the parameters and before .ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for anyone that has the same problem Prepare() solved it.
Use Add() for params and specify The SqlDbType. Prepare() will not work with AddWithValue().
At the end do Prepare() and then ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Ah, interesting. Glad to know you got it sorted. :)